# Angular download pdf file with blank page

Tags: angular, pdf

I trie to do download a pdf file from a String that I got from my backend and convert to blob in the angular but when I open the pdf, I have all pages of my pdf but they are empty

My angular code

```
 download() {
    const blob = new Blob([this.responseBody], {
      type: 'application/pdf'
    });
    const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(fileURL);
  }
```

My string look like this :

```
%PDF-1.4 %ª«¬­ 1 0 obj << /Creator (Apache FOP Version 2.1) /Producer (Apache FOP Version 2.1) /CreationDate (D:20221014064448Z) >> endobj 2 0 obj << /N 3 /Length 3 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream xwXSçÇßsNö`$!l{¥@
```

What wrong on my angular code ?

Comment: Can you show your actual reponse body? It seems kind of strange wrapping this object in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data format as base 64 first use bellow code,

```
 const byteArray = new Uint8Array(
  atob(this.responseBody)
    .split('')
    .map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0))
);
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' })
);
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

If not use bellow code,

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([this.responseBody], { type: 'application/pdf' })
);
window.open(url, '_blank');
```